# BeautifulSoup to extract URLs (same URL repeating)

Tags: python, regex, url, csv, beautifulsoup

I've tried using BeautifulSoup and regex to extract URLs from a web page. This is my code:

```
Ref_pattern = re.compile('<TD width="200"><A href="(.*?)" target=')
Ref_data = Ref_pattern.search(web_page)
if Ref_data:
    Ref_data.group(1)
data = [item for item in csv.reader(output_file)]
new_column1 = ["Reference", Ref_data.group(1)]
new_data = []
for i, item in enumerate(data):
    try:
        item.append(new_column1[i])
    except IndexError, e:
        item.append(Ref_data.group(1)).next()
    new_data.append(item)
```

Though it has many URLs in it, it just repeats the first URL. I know there's something wrong with

```
except IndexError, e:
    item.append(Ref_data.group(1)).next()
```

this part because if I remove it, it just gives me the first URL (without repetition). Could you please help me extract all the URLs and write them into a CSV file.
Thank you.

Comment: You are not using BeautifulSoup here, you are using a regular expression. Why not *actually* use BeautifulSoup here instead? `soup.select('td[width=200] a[href]')` would list the same sequence of links.

Comment: Also, `item.append()` alters `item` in-place so returns `None`. It is not clear what you are actually trying to achieve here.

Comment: Your regular expression will only ever find the first match anyway, there are no multiple matches to work with here.

Comment: Hi @MartijnPieters Thank you for your response. I tried that and I couldn't get the output. Probably the issue's with my approach and understanding. I'd truly appreciate if you could suggest a modified code that works.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do; do you want to add each URL to the existing CSV rows?

Comment: Yes. I'd like to extract all the URLs in the web page and write them to existing CSV rows.

Comment: Use BeautifulSoup to extract the urls for you. `for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True): print a['href']`

Comment: yeah, Martin is right; and you don't want to use regex for parsing.  at first I rejected this advice, but eventually (after beating my head against the wall) I agreed with the "experts."  lastly, if @hwnd's recommendation won't work, then post some more of the problem so we can run your (dummy) code and diagnose the problem.

Comment: @BeeSmears, I tried what hwnd has said. It works a little more than what I want. I'd like to only extract certain URLs and then append to an already existing CSV file as a new column. Please advise further.

Comment: @user3783999 would you please post code we can run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's not entirely clear what you're looking for, based on what you've stated, if there are specific elements (classes or id's or text, for instance) associated with the links you're attempting to extract, then you can do something like the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
string = """\
        <a href="http://example.com">Linked Text</a>
        <a href="http://example.com/link" class="pooper">Linked Text</a>
        <a href="http://example.com/page" class="pooper">Image</a>
        <a href="http://anotherexmpaple.com/page">Phone Number</a>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(string)

for link in soup.findAll('a', { "class" : "pooper" }, href=True, text='Linked Text'):
    print link['href']
```

As you can see, I am using the bs4's [attribute feature](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes) to select only those anchor tags that include the "pooper" class (`class="pooper"`), and then I am further narrowing the return values by passing a [text argument](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-text-argument) (`Linked Text` rather than `Image`).

Based on your feedback below, try the following code.  Let me know.

```
for items in soup.select("td[width=200]"):
    for link in items:
        link.findAll('a', { "target" : "_blank" }, href=True)
        print link['href']
```

Comment: @user3783999 I'm only seeing one type of target (`target="_blank"`).  d'you want link[href]'s associated with those targets?

Comment: Yes. I'd really appreciate if you could guide me to extract those 1000 (approx) URLs.

Comment: @user3783999 Added an edit.  Headed home, so I may be off the clock until tomorrow.  If it works, don't forget to accept it as the answer :).  Also, if you need to discuss creating `csv` files with the items you extract, I can likely provide a little help there, too.  Let me know.

Comment: I can write them to CSV file once I extract them. Thank you for asking. Thanks for your continuous response.

Comment: @user3783999 Did the code work?  It's working for me, but I don't know all of your criteria.  Let me know, mate.

Comment: @user3783999, if Bee's answer worked, please mark it as the accepted answer for future readers of your question (like me :)).  Thanks!